# How can I join an ubuntu 12.10 client to join a windows domain (server 2008)

Tags: command-line, windows, login, domain-server

In My office am using windows server 2008 recently am install ubuntu 12.10 in my offz its really awesome but Little bit am struggling about few configurations and settings... now also am struggling about one thing today am tried ubuntu 12.10 client join to windows server 2008 following This http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000384.htm website i did all commands but  am not get the log in window in ubuntu 12.10,my windows server in Active directory ubuntu is added  in user and Computers option who can i join ubuntu 12.10 to windows server any one help me....

Comment: This is the setup I used and I cannot see the option to log on to domain after I complete the setup.
I can ping domain with host name and IP address but does not have a log on to domain option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't particularly care for that guide they give, you should not need Samba just to log in. [Here](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/951-add-ubuntu-to-your-windows-active-directory) is a somewhat better guide in my opinion.

Also, do note that when you log in, you will now have to log in as domain\username  not just the username and you won't get a new log in screen just so you know.  The log in screen will look exactly the same, this only changes the back end stuff that you don't see.

Answer (score 1):

You can use likewise-open

**Open Terminal**

ping domain e.g. domain.com

ping doimain controller e.g. domaincontroller.domain.com

ping domain controller IP Address 192.168.X.X

**For this Process I used ¨root user¨**

$ sudo su

gedit /etc/hosts

**Put this below the first two lines:**

IPADDRESSOFDCSERVER   SERVERNAME
192.168.0.1       Ubuntuserver1

gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf

**look for line that says hosts and comment is out with ¨#¨
then add the following line above it:**

hosts:      files dns mdns4

gedit /etc/resolv.conf

**comment out everything with ¨#¨ and add line below**

search domain.com
nameserver  192.168.X.X (IP ADDRESS OF DOMAIN CONTROLLER)

gedit /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf

**Then add line below the ¨option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;¨**

supersede domain-name ¨domain.com¨;

prepend domain-name-servers 192.168.X.X; (IP ADDRESS OF DOMAIN CONTROLLER)

**Here I added the user I will be log into the machine with to a two group:**

sudo visudo

under #User privilege specification: put domain user
DOMAIN\username ALL=(ALL) ALL

**and**

under #Member of admin group may gain root privileges:

%DOMAIN\domain^users ALL=(ALL) ALL

**Then Install likewise with the following:**

apt-get install likewise-open likewise-open-gui

**Then join the domain:**

domainjoin-cli join --ou COMPUTERS DOMAIN.COM administrator

**This is opitional to allow you to just type in the username without the domain:**

lwconfig assumeDefaultDomain True

**Then you reboot the machine:**

sudo reboot

**After reboot you login:**

login with domain username

**from terminal you now check to see if all configuration went well:**

lw-get-status (to see if active Directory is there)

lw-enum-users (to see the user of active Directory)

**If errors should occur like not seeing the login page:**

Enable domain login on login screen

gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

**Acutally adding:** greeter-hide-users=true **(this hide the users so becareful with this one)**

greeter-show-manual-login=true **(This shows all users and login function)**

**To leave the domain**

sudo domainjoin-cli leave

Let me know if this helps!